# Stimulus build html element from rest API

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, stimulusjs, symfony5.4

Hello I have a **stimulus** code into my **symfony project**.
This code is calling a **rest API** which taking around 3 seconds to provide the response. This rest api return JSON.

This is my code :

```
import {Controller} from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import axios from "axios";


export default class extends Controller {
    static values = {
        url: String
    }

    connect() {
        axios.get(this.urlValue)
            .then((r) => {
                if (r.data !== null) {
                    let html
                    const tmp = JSON.parse(r.data)
                    if (tmp === null) {
                        html = document.createElement("div")
                        html.classList.add("alert", "alert-danger", "alert-dismissible", "fade", "show")
                        html.innerHTML += "Asset Number Not Valid";
                        html.innerHTML += "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn-close\" data-bs-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-label=\"Close\"></button>"
                    } else {
                        html = document.createElement("ul")
                        html.classList.add("list-group")
                        for(let key in tmp) {
                            html.innerHTML += "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + key + " : " + tmp[key] + "</li>";
                        }
                        html.innerHTML += "</ul>";
                    }
                    this.element.replaceWith(html);
                }
            })
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's building a list or display an error. This code is really simple and works well. I just don't like how html is build.

Do you have any other/cleaner way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach, basically leveraging the HTML Template element to move all of your HTML back into the HTML file.

When you are building too much HTML in your Stimulus controller it can get messy, instead think about the power of targets as being able to target any element including templates and even things you add dynamically.

### Controller

- We create some `template` targets for our HTML that we will use as a base to copy when inject.
- We also have an `error` and item` target name for being able to easily remove any error or items that get added.
- The `results` target will house the results (item templates) that get injected.
- Also we will use `innerText` instead of `innerHtml` for safety.

```js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [
    'error',
    'errorTemplate',
    'item',
    'itemTemplate',
    'results',
  ];

  static values = {
    url: String,
  };

  connect() {
    this.clearError();
    this.clearResults();

    fetch(/* or axios */)
      .then(/* json parsing etc */)
      .then((items) => {
        items.forEach((value) => {
          this.addResultItem(value);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // be sure to handle errors using nice promise like thing
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }

  clearError() {
    this.errorTarget && this.errorTarget.remove();
  }

  clearResults() {
    this.resultItemTargets.forEach((itemElement) => {
      itemElement.remove();
    });
  }

  showError() {
    const alert =
      this.errorTemplateTarget.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    this.prepend(alert);
  }

  addResultItem(value) {
    const item =
      this.itemTemplateTarget.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    item.innerText = value;
    this.resultsTarget.append(item);
  }
}
```

#### HTML

- Here we have our base `template` elements that let us set up any HTML we want for the `error` and `item` parts.
- The `template` elements have the target names that end in `template`
- Note that we have the `ul` always in the DOM but you can use css `:empty` to just hide it by default if there are no items in it.

```html
<section class="container" data-controller="results"
  data-results-url-value="https://myapi">
  <template data-results-target="itemTemplate">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-results-target="item">__VALUE__</li>
  </template>
  <template data-results-target="errorTemplate">
    <div data-results-target="error" class="alert alert-danger
      alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <!-- remember accessibility - use proper titles & role=alert when putting things in DOM -->
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"
        aria-label="Close"></button>
      <h3>Asset Number Not Valid</h3>
      <p>Details about the thing</p>
    </div>
  </template>
  <!-- use css to hide if :empty -->
  <ul class="list-group" data-results-target="results">
  </ul>
</section>
```

### Helpful links

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template (Template element)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend (add a new element to the top of another element)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API - browser supported alternative to axios
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty - CSS empty selector

Answer (score 0):

You can create HTML in separated functions below connect method, for example:

```
errorMessage() {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = `
    <p>Some HTML here</p>
    ... More html

  `

  return div;
}
```

Then in response you just call:

```
this.errorMessage();
```

The same goes for successful response. So in the end in your response you can either have `this.errorMessage()` or `this.appendList()` or whatever you gonna call your function.